# I am getting this error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.Node deploying war in Ubuntu tomcat server

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, javafx, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting this below error when deploying a war file (its a web service file)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.Node deploying war in Ubuntu tomcat server
After trying to start the war service which i deployed . When I check the status of the tomcat  server

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.Node
```

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu typically uses OpenJDK as its default JDK. JavaFX is not included by default. Assuming you are using Java 8, you can install it using `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjfx`. See also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1091157

Comment: Post the error messages as formatted text, not as screenshots. I'm intrigued as to why you are using JavaFX components in a web application; but as indicated in the previous comment you will have to make sure the JavaFX libraries and runtime are available.